# Excel Application Get Active Sheet

Tags: c#, .net, vsto, excel-2010, excel-interop

I'm trying to return the active sheet from the `workbook.SheetActivate` event as a `Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Worksheet` object but I'm having some real issues!

I'm creating worksheets at runtime by copying one worksheet, and then renaming it. The worksheet I'm copying is a template which houses the look and feel for each generated excel sheet.

I need to get the `Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Worksheet` object because I then need to add a button control to the stated excel sheet.

This is how I've tried to accomplish this:

```
void Application_SheetActivate(object Sh)
{
     Excel._Worksheet test = Sh as Excel._Worksheet;
     Worksheet worksheet = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(test);
     MessageBox.Show(worksheet.Name.ToString());
}
```

This works for the Sheet1, but the template sheet and anything else that gets started up gets this error:
`System.NullReferenceException. Object not sent to an instance of an object`. After running the debugger I can see that the first excel sheet is assigned correctly, but any other ones aren't... I know what the error states and what it means.

What am I doing incorrectly here? When a sheet tab gets clicked, all I want to be able to do is return a `Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel.Worksheet` type, but boy I've never had so many issues!

Comment: What line of code exactly fires the exception?

Comment: `Worksheet worksheet = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(test);` This works for ONLY the the first sheet, everything else just throws the exception.

Comment: Use the HasVstoObject method if you want to determine whether the native Office object has an extended object in your customization. This method returns true if the native Office object has an extended object, and false otherwise. See [Getting Extended Objects from Native Office Objects in Document-Level Customizations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc668196%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.